# Unable to remove Google Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I am trying to remove a few Google Chrome extensions from my system, go to the Extensions menu, click on the Trash icon, confirm that I want to remove these extensions, and they get removed for a while, but they reappear when I restart my system. This has been going on from quite some time now, I do not know why.

Here is the list of extensions that I am trying to remove: Freemake Video Convertor, Google Docs, Entrusted, Avast! Antivirus and Be Limitless.

What is wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you have synchronized your Google Chrome with instances of Google Chrome on other devices, and in addition to synchronizing your bookmarks, you have inadvertently selected to sync your extensions as well. So the first time you open Google Chrome on a new day, Chrome searches for the master device's data to sync to, and then restores your extensions by syncing the data on your computer with the data from the master device.

Check your sync settings to see if they are correct. Chrome menu **⋮** -> *Settings* -> *People* . If you are syncing your extensions, you can change it from there.

Comment: What should I do about this? I use only one system.

Comment: Check your sync settings to see if they are correct. _Google Chrome_ -> _Settings_ -> _Advanced sync settings_. If your are syncing your extensions, you can change it from there.

Comment: If this works, I shall kiss your feet. I have been trying to uninstall extension Vaudix from Chrome for two days now. Running different virus and anti-spyware programmes, to no avail.

Comment: Even if this answer doesn't work you can try  to remove the stubborn malware from Chrome by: 1. Export bookmarks from Chrome to HTML file 2. Uninstall Google Chrome and reinstall Google Chrome. 3. Import bookmarks to the newly installed Chrome from the HTML file that you saved. Step-by-step instructions from support.google.com/chrome: [Import or export bookmarks](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Settings page in Google Chrome
2. At the top there is a link for [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync) - click that
3. Scroll to the bottom and click *Reset sync*

This will reset all those extensions and apps you've installed and deleted that keep showing back up.